# How to render and update multiple timers at the same time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm trying to build a function to display multiple counters rendered from stored data on Firestore.

When I just run the static calculations for the counters they return the correct strings, but when I try to run that function every second, I get different output:

The display shows a successive number count (like for instance 16, 17, 18) instead of the 3 countdowns (in the format "T- days, hours, minutes, seconds").

If I build the interval inside the function, then I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

**Countdown Function**

```
function countThis(date){
    const now = new Date().getTime();      
    const distance = date - now;
    const days = Math.abs(Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    const hours = Math.abs(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    const minutes = Math.abs(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
    const seconds = Math.abs(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));

    if (distance > 0) { 
        const calc = `T- ${days}D ${hours}H ${minutes}M ${seconds}S`;
        return calc;
    }
    else if (distance < 0) {                        
        const calc = `T+ ${days}D ${hours}H ${minutes}M ${seconds}S`;
        return calc;
    }
};
```

**Counter Rendering**

```
const counters = (data) => {            
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const date = data.timestamp.toDate();
        const counter = 
            `<div class="counter">
                <h5>` + dateFormat(date) + `</h5>
                <h4 class="activeCount">` + setInterval(countThis(date), 1000) + `</h4>
                <p class="micro">${data.title}</p>
            </div>`;
        html += counter;
    });
    counterModule.innerHTML += html;
}
```

Comment: *"I get a bug"*: please be more precise. A bug can be anything. An error message, a wrong output, at the wrong time, or ...?

Comment: Just added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- `setInterval` returns a unique identifier of the created interval: that's not what you want to output in your HTML
- `setInterval` expects a call back function, but instead you *execute* a function, and pass its return value to `setInterval`.
- You call `setInterval` for each count down, while you should just have one timer that updates all count downs.
- The HTML is only set to `counterModule` once and never again. You would need to update the HTML at each interval tick.

Here is a correction for `counters`:

```
const counters = (data) => {        
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const date = data.timestamp.toDate();
        // Don't call setInterval here:
        const counter = 
            `<div class="counter">
                <h5>${dateFormat(date)}</h5>
                <h4 class="activeCount">${countThis(date)}</h4>
                <p class="micro">${data.title}</p>
            </div>`;
        html += counter;
    });
    counterModule.innerHTML = html; // NOT +=, but just =
}
```

And the main code should have this, assuming that `data` is defined:

```
setInterval(() => counters(data), 1000);
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, how do I define  'data'

Comment: You had it defined when you yourself called `counters`? Or how else did you call it? You did not provide that information in your question...

Comment: I call it here: `db.collection('counters').onSnapshot(snapshot => {counters(snapshot.docs);});`. I do get the data rendered, `but the setInterval(() => counters(data), 1000);` is returning `data is not defined`

Comment: So your data is `snapshot.docs`. Obviously you should not change what you currently pass to `counters`. So where you currently have `counters(snapshot.docs);` you should do `setInterval(() => counters(snapshot.docs), 1000);`

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks Mr. Trincot. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I learned JS a while ago, but never used it. So I'm kinda lost.